# Tomcat 7 requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat

I am creating a simple logout screen that would allow me to logout of a web app.  My code snippet for the JSP file is:

```
<form action="Logout">
    Are you sure you want to logout?
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Yes">
</form>
```

My Logout class code snippet is as follows:

```
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String strAnswer=request.getParameter("logout");
        if (strAnswer.equals("Yes")) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  My web.xml snippet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
   <display-name>ThisIsATest</display-name>
   <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Logout</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Logout</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Logout</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I pressed the Yes button, I get a requested resource is not available message with my path being http://localhost:8080/Logout?logout=Yes.  Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What's your mapping for that `Logout` servlet in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Please see original question for web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the servlet and servlet mapping for Logout in web.xml.  That solved the problem!